# Use macro inside CloudFormation Conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I've written a macro (called `BucketChecker`) that takes in an s3 bucket name and checks if it already exists.
The fragment will return true or false accordingly.

I would like to use this macro in a `Conditions` section as described in this article: https://cloudnineapps.com/blogs/cloud-computing/how-to-create-dynamic-condition-expressions-in-aws-cloudformation-using-macros/.

The idea is to use this as a condition in my template like this:

```
Conditions:
  CreateBucket:
    Fn::Equals: ['false', 'Fn::Transform': {
      Name: BucketChecker,
      Parameters: {
        Operation: 'bucketExists',
        BucketName: 'my-bucket'
      }}]

Resources:
  MyBucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Condition: CreateBucket   # -> only create it if doesn't yet exist
    Properties:      
      BucketName: 'my-bucket'
```

But cfn-linter gives me the error: `E8003 Fn::Equals element must be a supported function (Ref, Fn::FindInMap, Fn::Sub, Fn::Join, Fn::Select, Fn::Split)`

My main question is: is it even possible to achieve this using CloudFormation? If yes, what's wrong with my template?
The linked article seems to be doing exactly the same, but mine doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried deploying it? The cfn-linter may be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @Marcin. It indeed does work regardless of cfn-linter nagging me about it. I'll answer my own question in case someone runs into this same problem.

Comment: [The Linter does not fully understand all transforms yet](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/issues/476)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The `cfn-linter` was **incorrectly** classifying the `Fn::Transform` as malformed.

Deploying the stack confirmed that there are **no issues** with the `Fn::Transform`.